# What function to use in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Working on an Excel project and can't figure out what forumula to use. Any help would be awesome!

B39 has the transportation costs for 2013. C39-F39 have transportation costs for 2014-2017. C20-F20 have the expected percent change in energy costs for each year. The value of B39 is $6 billion. The values of C39-G39 are dependent on 2 things. First, you take the value from the prior year. Second, for each percent change in energy costs, you add $25 million to transportation costs. Thus, if C20 equals 1%, C39 should equal $6 billion + $25 million.

I tried to describe this the best way possible. If something isn't clear, let me know.

Comment: It would help if you added a screen shot or a mock up of the sheet please.

Comment: Question was already answered, but will make sure to include screenshot next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this and check if this is what you wanted.

Formula:

```
C39 = SUM(B39, PRODUCT(C20,25000000))
```

Drag this formula to other cells in the row.
So,

```
D39 = SUM(C39, PRODUCT(D20,25000000))
E39 = SUM(D39, PRODUCT(E20,25000000))
F39 = SUM(E39, PRODUCT(F20,25000000))
G39 = SUM(F39, PRODUCT(G20,25000000))
```

[image: Check this]